# Connect to OPC server in C# with VS2013

Tags: c#, opc

I trying to connect an OPC server with C# in VS2013.
Here is the most important two lines:

```
OpcServer Srv = new OpcServer();
int rtc = Srv.Connect(...);
```

The facts which I know:

- I'm runing this code another PC, not on localhost (in OPC server)
- I know the IP address of OPC server
- I know the URI for the OPC: opcda://Helmholz.OPC.S7.DA/{8C5FBBB7-0A62-4fcb-99CC-BEE0D4B0B6DE}

But, I don't know how can I define this information in the Srv.Connect command.

Comment: Which OPC library are you using? We have no idea what `OpcServer` is. Do you have a link to docs for it? For example, you [might need](http://advosol.com/manuals/opcdanet/topic908.html) to do something like this: `Srv.Connect("1.2.3.4", "Helmholz.OPC.S7.DA");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OPC NET API, you probably want to use something like:

```
opcda://1.2.3.4/Helmholz.OPC.S7.DA/{8C5FBBB7-0A62-4fcb-99CC-BEE0D4B0B6DE}
```

I wrote an article about "OPC URLs": http://www.opclabs.com/resources/developer-blog/1086-a-partial-story-of-opc-urls?showall=&limitstart=